# php foreach elements when echoed in <id> are not quoted togther

Tags: php, foreach

I have a PHP file that sends data to a 'ul' html element via ajax.

```
foreach ($data as $value) {
    echo '<li id='. $value .'>'.$value.'</li>';
}
```

$data is a php array of the results received from SQL. So data will often be an array of 10 different words.
It works fine when the $value is one word.For example lets say $value = word1 (only one word, no spaces.)

```
    <li id='word1'>word1</li>        //this is correct
```

However, once in a while data while have an element that is two words. If $value is two words (word1 word2)(fish sticks), the 'li id' becomes:

```
<li id='fish' sticks> fish sticks</li> //this is wrong
```

Notice how in the 'id' word2(sauce) is not inside the quotes.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you aren't quoting your HTML attributes. Also, spaces in `id` attributes are not valid. You'll need to normalise the value for use in the attribute. Try something like this

```
function normaliseIdAttribute($id) {
    return htmlspecialchars(strtolower(preg_replace(
        '/\W+/', '-', $id)));
}

foreach ($data as $value) {
    printf('<li id="%s">%s</li>',
        normaliseIdAttribute($value),
        htmlspecialchars($value));
}
```

Comment: You da man Phil. Solving problem I didn't even know I had. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need use `"` to quote your id.

```
echo '<li id="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</li>'
```